# Jetpack Component screens overlaps, or partially rendered, when being navigated with Jetpack Compose navigation controller

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Here is the [symptom - Youtube](https://youtu.be/gHzVhHC2Lss)

It looks like screens are partially rendered, or overlapped, when being navigated with Jetpack Compose navigation controller.

I try to find an answer one, but no one seems to meet this problem at all.

Here are related code snippets

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NavHostAuth(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = NavRoutesAuth.SignIn.route
    ) {

        composable(NavRoutesAuth.SignIn.route) {
            EnterAnimation {
                ScreenSignInWithInputValidationDebounce(navController)
            }
        }

        composable(NavRoutesAuth.SignUp.route) {
            EnterAnimation {
                ScreenSignUpWithInputValidationDebounce(navController)
            }
        }

    }
}

enum class NavRoutesAuth(val route: String) {
    SignIn("auth/signin"),
    SignUp("auth/signup"),
}
```

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun EnterAnimation(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = visible,
        modifier = Modifier,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { -40 })
                + expandVertically(expandFrom = Alignment.Top)
                + fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
        exit = slideOutVertically()
                + shrinkVertically()
                + fadeOut()
    ) {
        content()
    }

}
```

What might be the cause?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the [Animations in Navigation Compose blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animations-in-navigation-compose-36d48870776b) and look at [Accompanist Navigation Animation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-animation/)? That's how you should be adding enter/exit transitions to your destinations. What you're doing is going to conflict with the default cross fade animations.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for your reply. Even with removal of EnterAnimation` in the `NavHostAuth`, they still overlap with each other as the same, which makes me suspect that the default behavior does not work either.

Comment: Do you have a video of what you're experiencing with default behavior? A cross fade will mean that both screens are visible at the same time as one fades out at the same time as the other fades in.

Comment: I commented out all the code related to `EnterAnimation` in `NavHostAuth`, and tried with a fresh re-installation of the app, it behaves the same: the screens still overlap.

Comment: If I separate these two screens, put them into different activity, with each activity loading only one JCScreen, and have them communicate with `Intent`, everything works fine: the default animation shows up as expected.

Comment: Again, do you have a video, gif, anything that shows overlapping screen when you leave out your `EnterAnimation` code?